# What's the difference between lock_time and unlock_time in pam_tally2?

Tags: linux, pam

I realize that [pam_tally2](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_tally2.8.html) is deprecated in favor of [pam_faillock](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_faillock), but I have to use it anyway. What I don't get is the difference between these two options. They sound identical to me:

```
           lock_time=n
               Always deny for n seconds after failed attempt.

           unlock_time=n
               Allow access after n seconds after failed attempt. If
               this option is used the user will be locked out for the
               specified amount of time after he exceeded his maximum
               allowed attempts. Otherwise the account is locked until
               the lock is removed by a manual intervention of the
               system administrator.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be clearer it `lock_time`'s description said "after *each* failed attempt." `lock_time` blocks further login attempts for *n* seconds once you fail a login attempt. `unlock_time` blocks login attempts for *n* seconds after the maximum allowed failed login attempts (specified using `deny=n`).

You can check the source code to see that [`unlock_time` is only used in the block for checking `deny`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/v1.4.0/modules/pam_tally2/pam_tally2.c#L523-L551), and [`lock_time` is used for each tally check](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/v1.4.0/modules/pam_tally2/pam_tally2.c#L570-L593).